# Can the precompiles in Byzantium for pairings be used for implementation of BGLS verification?

Tags: pairings, bls-signature

BGLS [[1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-39200-9_26)] is an aggregate signature scheme by Boneh et al., that allows aggregation of BLS signatures on n different messages from n different signers. What I want to achieve is to verify such signatures in a smart contract, using the new precompiled contracts for pairing operations (pairing equality, scalar multiplication, and point addition) released with Byzantium.

Verification of a BGLS signature of $n$ signers is done through checking equality $$e(g_1, σ) == \prod_i^n e(v_i, h_i)$$
where:

- $e : G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow G_T$ is a bilinear pairing/mapping
- $g_1$ is a generator of $\mathbb{G}_1$
- $\sigma$ is the aggregate signature
- $v_i$ is the public key of signer $i$
- $h_i$ is the hash of the signed message of signer $i$

**Question:** 
Does anyone know whether we can formulate the equality above in terms of only three operations: point additions, scalar multiplications, and equality checks?

**Thoughts:** 
What I was thinking is that we could rewrite the equality as $$e(g_1, σ) ==  e(\prod_i^n v_i, \prod_i^n h_i)$$
but I have not been able to prove whether that is correct.

**Background:**

- Point additions, scalar multiplications, and equality checks are currently the only operations supported in Ethereum.
- I asked a similar, but more Solidity-specific, [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51421/how-can-we-verify-bgls-aggregate-signatures-in-solidity) on the 
  Ethereum StackExchange.
- Another user posted a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/can-the-precompiles-in-ethereum-byzantium-for-pairings-be-used-for-implementatio) on verifying BLS signatures (which is essentially a BGLS signature for one signer). My question can be seen as a follow-up on that.